# unicode not printing on when imported from text file python

Tags: python, text, unicode, python-unicode

I am reading in a text file from python and when it prints the Unicode, it does not print the symbol.

input.txt:

```
hello world
\u00a9
```

code:

```py
from pathlib import Path 
with open('input.txt','r') as file:
    txt = Path('input.txt').read_text()
    print(txt)
```

output:

```
hello world 
\u00a9
```

expected output:

```
hello world
°
```

Comment: Please edit your question and do some formatting. The readability is not very good. But one can see, that your file doesn't contain a `°`. Your file contains the text `\u00a9` and that is printed. There is a difference between the characters `\u00a9` as characters in a text file and a string definition `"\u00a9"` in the program itself. Check `print("\u00a9")` vs `print(r"\u00a9")`.

Answer (score 2):

The data printed is exactly what is in the file.  To translate Unicode escapes you will need to specify that as an encoding.  The original code was also mixing file reading methods, so here's both versions:

```py
with open('input.txt',encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    txt = f.read()
print(txt)
```

```py
from pathlib import Path
txt = Path('input.txt').read_text(encoding='unicode-escape')
print(txt)
```

Output (both versions):

```
hello world
©
```

Note that `\u00a9` is the copyright symbol, not degree symbol.  The degree symbol is `\u00b0`.